# How to properly position the arrow in <details> CSS

Tags: css, html

I would like to change the position of the arrow that appears in details. I've tried float:left but if the line is too big, like the one in the example above, the arrow moves on the start of the line underneath when I resize the window. I would like it to stay on besides the very first letter on the first row.

How can I do that?

Example:

```html
<details>
  <summary>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut 
  gravida iaculis arcu, et hendrerit arcu. Morbi rhoncus ex quam, quis. 
 </summary>
  Content goes here.
</details>
<style>
 summary::-webkit-details-marker {
 display: none
}
 summary:after {
 content: "+";
 color: #fff;
 float: left;
 }

 details[open] summary:after {
 content: "-";
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `:before` instead of `:after`

```css
 summary::-webkit-details-marker {
 display: none
}
 summary:before {
 content: "+";
 color: red;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 }

 details[open] summary:before {
 content: "-";
 }
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut 
  gravida iaculis arcu, et hendrerit arcu. Morbi rhoncus ex quam, quis. 
 </summary>
  Content goes here.
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can position the marker using absolute positioning

```css
details {
  width: 20em;
  margin: auto;
}

summary {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: -.5em;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut gravida iaculis arcu, et hendrerit arcu. Morbi rhoncus ex quam, quis.</summary>
  Content goes here.
</details>
```