# How to position <detail> marker to come after <summary>

Tags: html, css

I have several data items, some of which have **Details** & **Summary** tags, which reveal extra input options. Standard HTML puts the details marker on the left, which breaks the alignment. I would like to move the details marker to come after the Summary text. In the image below, I would like to move the triangle to the right of "Title: Book Club"

[image]
[image]

```html
<details>
<summary> Title: Book Club</summary>
This revealed area tells more about the course and maybe has a form in it.
</details>
```

Related: [How to properly position the arrow in <details> CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49924024/how-to-properly-position-the-arrow-in-details-css)

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the intended HTML. This doesn't look like a proper use of `details`. Are you trying to nest `detail` elements?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can hide the default arrow and replace it with your own:

```css
details>summary {
 
  list-style: none;
}
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none
}

summary::after {
  content: ' ►';
}
details[open] summary:after {
  content: " ▼";
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary> Title: Book Club</summary>
  This revealed area tells more about the course and maybe has a form in it.
</details>
```

Comment: I tested this in Edge, Chrome, Firefox and Safari; and `::-webkit-details-marker` only works in Safari. To support those other browsers, you need to add `summary::marker { content: none; }`. The `::marker` pseudo-element only supports certain CSS properties, so you need to use `content: none` instead of `display: none`. Also note that Safari _doesn't_ support `::marker` (for this purpose anyway) so you do need both rules.

Comment: Warning: the code of j08691 is relevant, but false in case of nested elements. Add a child selector:
`details[open] > summary::before`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is the best choice, here's an alternative that uses `transform: scaleX(-1)` to flip elements so they display as a mirror image.

1. Add a `<b>` inside `<summary>`. Any text should be inside the `<b>`.
2. Assign `position: relative` and `transform: scaleX(-1)` to `<summary>`.
3. Assign `display: inline-block`, `position: absolute`, `right: 6px`, and `transform: scaleX(-1)` to the `<b>`.

   <sup>Almost any [flow or phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content) type element, it doesn't have to be a `<b>`.</sup>

   <sup>Actual length may vary, 6px is a length that looks acceptable with these particular styles.</sup>

***Note: The original solution involved the use of `::-webkit-details-marker` which is now [deprecated](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3A-webkit-details-marker). Refer [here](https://chromestatus.com/feature/6730096436051968) for what to use in place of `::-webkit-details-marker`***

```css
:root {
  font: 400 small-caps 3vw/1.2 'Segoe UI'
}

summary {
  position: relative;
  border: 2.5px inset grey;
  padding: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

summary b {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 96%;
  margin: 2.5vh auto;
}

i {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <b>Book Club</b>
  </summary>
  <label><i>Game of Thrones,</i> <cite>George R. R. Martin</cite></label>
  <label><i>Chronicles of Amber,</i> <cite>Roger Zelazny</cite></label>
  <label><i>Tales of the Dying Earth,</i> <cite>Jack Vance</cite></label>
  <label><i>Stranger in a Strange Land,</i> <cite>Robert A. Heinlein</cite></label>
</details>
```

Comment: This does not appear to work (anymore?), though I also don't know why. Position on `summary::marker` just seems to be ignored (chrome)

Comment: Thanks for notifying me, @phil294 `::-webkit-details-marker` has been deprecated since Feb 2021 and looks like [`::marker`](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3Amarker) may have different behaior with Safari (IDK don't have a Mac). I've updated my answer with a strange but effective solution.