# Error styling the Details/Summary marker in Safari/Webkit

Tags: css, webkit

When using the `<details>` tag, I want to display the flippy triangle to the right of the `<summary>` element.

So, instead of the default:

`▶ My Cool List` (left-aligned)

I want to do this:

`My Cool list ▶` (right-aligned)

And here it is working in Chrome:

[image: chrome correct]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758098/how-to-position-detail-marker-to-come-after-summary) helped me write the CSS, which works on Chrome and Firefox:

```
// Right-align all summaries.
details > summary {
  list-style: none; // Remove the default arrow.
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; // Vertically center the arrow.
}
details > summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}
details > summary::after {
  content:  '▶';
}
details[open] > summary::after {
  content: "▼";
}
```

However, on Safari (tested Mojave on desktop + iOS14 + iOS12), the flippy triangle is pushed to a new line:

```
My Cool List
▶
```

In Safari:

[image: safari broken flippy triangle]

So, how do I get Safari to show the flippy triangle on the same line like Firefox + Chrome?  It seems this problem is caused by the combination of the use of `display: flex` with the `::after` pseudoelement, but I don't know much about frontend development so I'm at a loss to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Safari doesn't handle `<p>` tags in the `<summary>`; when I removed those tags, I didn't even need to use flex to right-align the pseudoelement.

Answer (score 1):

You can add browser-specific CSS to overcome the `display: flex;` for `<summary>` issue.

For CSS

```
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) { @media {

    details > summary { 

        display: block; 

    }
}}
```

For SCSS

```
    @media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm)
    { @supports (-webkit-appearance:none) {

    details > summary { 

        display: block; 

    }
}}
```

Comment: What does that have to do with the list style?