# Styling the <details> element

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to change the style of details element from ‘▶’ and ‘▼’ to ‘>’and'<‘ ? with CSS code?

```
details > summary {
list-style-type: ">";}
details[open] > summary {
list-style-type: "<";}
details > summary {
list-style: none;}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to position <detail> marker to come after <summary>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758098/how-to-position-detail-marker-to-come-after-summary)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem wanting to style the details element and found a solution adding the arrow at the end, hiding the original arrow and adding an empty content corner and rotation it.

Link to article by Scott O'Hara; https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2022/09/12/details-summary.html